# Can not make MoreThanOrEqual work in TypeOrm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm trying to make some filter, and meet the problem: MoreThanOrEqual is not working,

```js
 this.freelanceRepo.find({
          join: {
              alias: "freelance",
              leftJoinAndSelect: {
                categories: "freelance.categories"
              }
          },
          order:{id:'ASC'},
          where:{price_hours:MoreThanOrEqual(30)}//is not working
      })
```

I tried also the query builders

```js
this.freelanceRepo.createQueryBuilder("freelance")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("freelance.categories", "categories")
        .orderBy("freelance.id", "ASC")
        .where("freelance.price_hours = price_hours", {price_hours:MoreThanOrEqual(filterPrice)})
        .take(10)
        .skip(skippedItems)
        .getMany();
```

Here is my entity:

```js
@Entity({name: "fl_freelance"})
export class Freelance {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({default: false})
    is_active: boolean

    @Column({nullable:true})
    price_hours: number
    
    @OneToOne(() => User, user => user.freelance)
    @JoinColumn({name: "users_id"})
    users: User

    @ManyToMany(() => Categories, categories => categories.freelance)
    categories: Categories[]
}
```

have no idea what was gone wrong, thanks for your answers

Comment: Could you enable [logging](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging#enabling-logging) and check whether the generated query is what you are expecting? You can also run the same query in your postgres client and see whether it has any issues. You can update the question with those queries if you still find it hard to solve. For me, I don't see an issue in the way you have used `MoreThanOrEqual` in `find`. Also, when you say not working, does it throw you an error, or it just returns you an empty array?

Comment: It didn't throw any error, it just returns an empty array

Comment: Were you able to log the generated query to the terminal?

Comment: I tried it in postman and in terminal

Comment: Did you add the query logging? Then in terminal you can see the query typeorm is executing. It will be easy to find the problem if we can see the actual query that typeorm executes in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, I have done it that way, and it works

```js
return await this.freelanceRepo.createQueryBuilder("freelance")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("freelance.categories", "categories")
        .orderBy("freelance.id", "ASC")
        .where("freelance.price_hours >= :price_hours", {price_hours:10})
        .take(10)
        .skip(skippedItems)
        .getMany();
```